# Implicit complexity and interpretation of total languages

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, polynomial-time, interpreters

In implicit complexity theory we construct languages that characterize what can be computed in various complexity classes. One major result is [Bellantoni and Cook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sacook/homepage/ptime.pdf) where they show that $FP$ can be characterized by such a language (called system $B$).

I have the following beliefs about system $B$

- System B can encode all functions which can be computed in polynomial time
- All terms in System $B$ normalize in polynomial time
- Because all System $B$ terms normalize (in any amount of time) System $B$ is total
- Because all System $B$ terms normalize in polynomial time System $B$ can interpret System $B$

I have the following beliefs a computability as well

- [If a language can interpret itself then it is not total](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/24994/1546)
- System $B$ can interpret it self so System $B$ is not total

So I seem to believe contradictory things now; namely that System $B$ is total and that System $B$ is not total. Writing out like this makes me realize that the error is almost certainly in the last line of my beliefs about System $B$. So it must be the case that System $B$ can't interpret itself but I don't actually understand why this is the case. Is there a program input pair such that interpreting it takes greater than polynomial time? Further still System $B$ is just one such system among all characterizations of complexity classes on which I could apply this faulty reasoning so the answer should not be specific to System $B$ but to all such implicit characterizations of complexity classes.

Comment: I was thinking on the lines that... If the system guarantees a polytime computation bound...for all inputs...isnt it total by definition.

Comment: I'd say so. But this only furthers my confusion by cementing what I already believed.

Comment: Done. Doing so also helped me think though this a bit but I'm still confused.

Comment: You should clarify what you believe and what you (think you) know. Since you've accepted [Andrej Bauer's theorem](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/24994/1546) clearly the set of "beliefs" about System B is wrong. Which of them are theorems?

Comment: Everything *but* the statement "System B can interpret System B" is a theorem. Everything but Andrej's proof from that post is also per-reviewed. So I'm quite convinced that System B can't interpret System B. In fact I would even go so far as to say this constitutes a proof of this fact! My problem is that this seems crazy. I can't think of a counterexample (e.g. a program input pair that can't be evaluated in polynomial time) and I have a strong intuition that System B should be able to interpret System B. But I have no proof of he matter (and indeed I don't think I can have one).

Comment: One other distinct possibility is that I have misunderstood  Bellantoni and Cook's paper.

Comment: "In fact I would even go so far as to say this constitutes a proof of this fact!" -- I have the same impression. "I can't think of a counterexample" -- So? Many impossibility proofs are the same. Look at the halting problem: there is no single program you can not decide the halting property for. It's the entirety of all programs that is the problem. "I have a strong intuition" -- so your intuition is flawed! Time to adjust. :) (Don't worry, happens to everybody.) Remember: "I can not see a counter-example" does not mean something is true. (In science. \*sigh\*)

Comment: The halting problem seems like a good analogy. I'll settle with showing why the following proof is wrong. Say I write an interpreter for System B in my favorite programming language (I can easily do this). For any program input pair the running time will be polynomial. In fact the running time will be polynomial in the input size (which is smaller than the pair size). So interpreting system B is a problem in the class $FP$...which means System B should be able to do it. This seems like a believable proof that System B can interpret system B to me.

Comment: it would be helpful if you define more of the obscure terms, and also is there anything on wikipedia that can be cited? & think this all may fit better on [cstheory.se] although maybe just asking for clarification doesnt qualify as "research"

Comment: I never really know where I should post quite frankly. It's a bit advanced for here but I never know if my question is "research level". I don't think there is a wikipedia article on this material. it's a bit niche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As concluded via non-direct means in discussion interpreting a polytime program cannot be done in polynomial time in general. The following example shows this directly.

The trick is that for the interpreter to run in polynomial time there must be an polynomial that bounds the running time for *every* input. This pretty obviously isn't going to hold for System-$B$ because a small constant increase in program size can increase the order of the polynomial that bounds it by a constant amount. The trick you can fall into (and I indeed fell into) is to think that because for each program the running time is bounded a polynomial that the interpreter will run in polynomial time which is pretty embarrassingly obviously false when you write it out like this. It's running time on certain inputs will be bounded by some polynomial but that's the case for any program that always terminates.

So say there is a program, $I$ in System-$B$ that interprets System-$B$ and has running time in $O(n^k)$. Say I had another program, $P$, that ran in $O(n^K)$ with $K > k$. We could speed up P to $O(n^k)$ by simply running it though the interpreter first. So suddenly you have a huge speed up on $P$ that you shouldn't be able to get. In general $I$ could speed up any program slower than it.

I don't have a proof there is no $k$ such that every polytime function can be computed in $O(n^k)$ but it seems fairly obviously the case.

Comment: the last sentence is a tautology...? ie essentially by definition?

Comment: I fumbled my words, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

> If a language can interpret itself then it is not total

I take this to mean that if there is a universal machine for a class in the class itself, the class can not be total (i.e. there have to be non-total functions in the class). What you probably have in mind is that the class can not be the class of *all* total computable functions since we know that one to be not recursively enumerable.

However, that does not say anything about any other set of total functions.

For instance, all polynomial-time TMs can be simulated by a single polynomial-time TM. Assuming computable enumerations $M_i$ of all TMs and $p_j$ of the polynomials; both exist. Now consider the following machine `UPM` (universal polynomial machine):

```
UPM(<i,j>, n) :
  simulate M_i(n) for p_j(n) steps
  if the computation halts
    return M_i(n)
  else
    return 0
  end
```

This machine clearly exists (i.e. the described function is computable). Computing $p_j(n)$ and simulating $M_i(n)$ takes only polynomial time (some polynomial effort per simulated step) in $n$ and the size of the $M_i$ (effectively $|\langle i,j \rangle|$), so `UPM` is a polynomial-time machine itself.

Comment: How does the class of functions that can be computed in polynomial time not contain the function that turing machine encodes? If it does contain that function then the class must not be total right? I must be missing something but I'm just not sure what.

Comment: It certainly *does* contain `UPM`. Whyever would it not? The *claim* is that the set of polynomial-time functions/machines contains its own universal machine. Why should that not be possible? Do you have a particular theorem in mind?

Comment: The one Andre presented here which seems quite reasonable to me: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24986/a-total-language-that-only-a-turing-complete-language-can-interpret

Comment: @Jake Andrej's setup is different. I don't assume to have a decidable programming language for the set of all polynomial-time function. See also [this comment of his](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24986/a-total-language-that-only-a-turing-complete-language-can-interpret#comment62281_24994). Note that the enumeration works by enforcing the running-time bound by just aborting.

Comment: Fair enough. But Andre's case corresponds to my case as near as I understand it. The set of programs of System B is decidable. It seems to fit into Andre's format as near as I can tell.

Comment: @Jake I see, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: FYI, it is possible to define a strongly-typed language which is total and which has a self-interpreter by using the type system to eliminate the diagonalisation argument: http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/popl16/popl16-full.pdf

Comment: Could that actually be what is happening here? It seems unlikely to me given the lack of any real structure to System B's type system but indeed it *does* have a type system.

Comment: @Jake The separation between grammar-based syntax and type system only exists in the realm of programming languages. In formal languages, both come together and are just a language.

Comment: The aforementioned paper suggests multiple times that with the reason and argument like Andre's doesn't work in System-F-omega is because the type system doesn't allow the kind of diagonalization he did for certain representations of programs. The question is weather or not System B a type system that makes it the kind of language where this is the case. My guess is that because terms in System B are basically just functions from natural numbers to natural numbers that Andre's setup holds and that there isn't enough structure to represent some representation that disallows diagonalization